# Who's going to the INFORMS Annual Meeting in Indianapolis?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, events

I am! Helps that I have family in Indianapolis, will make this a combo work trip / vacation.  Hope to meet some of you there.

Answer (score 3):

I'm planning to go (although, as von Moltke the Elder noted, the first casualty in every battle is the plan).